# Angular Momentum for collection of particles: question on Wiki proof

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, momentum, torque

I'm following the [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Collection_of_particles) page on angular momentum for a collection of particles.  What should $\mathbf V$ be defined as in terms of the collection of particles with $\mathbf v_i$? $\mathbf V = \mathbf v_0 + ... +\mathbf v_n$?

$$
\mathbf L = \mathbf R \times M \mathbf V + \sum_i \mathbf r_i \times m_i \mathbf v_i
$$
$$
M = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i
$$
$$
\mathbf R = \frac {1}{M} \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \mathbf r_i
$$
where $\mathbf R$ is the position vector of the center of mass, $\mathbf V$ is the velocity vector of the center of mass, $\mathbf r_i$ is the position vector of particle $i$, $\mathbf v_i$ is the velocity vector of particle $i$.

[image]

Comment: [Wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Collection_of_particles) is very detailed and contains the  answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol $\textbf{V}$ represents the velocity of the center of mass position $\textbf{R}$.

$$\textbf{V}=\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{R}=\frac{1}{M}\sum_i m_i \textbf{V}_i$$

Also, you seem to have some definitions slightly off. The symbols $\textbf{R}_i$ and $\textbf{V}_i$ are the position and velocity of the $i$'th particle with respect to the origin of the coordinate system. On the other hand, the symbols $\textbf{r}_i$ and $\textbf{v}_i$ denote the position and velocity of the $i$'th particle with respect to the center-of-mass position (which in general is moving, unlike the fixed origin).